# Add physical disk to KVM virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I'm setting up a file server (nas4free) as a KVM virtual machine on a Ubuntu Server 12.04 system.

How do I add physical hard drives directly to the VM so they can be used by the guest (nas4free), but not the host?

Specifically the hard drive I'd like to mount is /dev/sda (which is not currently mounted on the server.)

So far I've found two solutions but I haven't gotten either to work.

The first is from [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/261703/kvm-guest-using-physical-sata-disk) where it's suggested to use virt-manager. I haven't gotent this to work because when I try to select an existing drive nothing is being listed. My best guess as to why this is, is because I'm using virt-manager over ssh and not connecting as root, should that make a difference?

The second solution I've found [here](http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/3035-add-physical-disks-to-linux-guest-%28kvm%29) is to just run the command (modified for my system)

```
qm set nas4free -virtio /dev/sda
```

but that seems to require proxmox which I don't have installed and doesn't seem to be in the default repositories?

Finally, once the above is sorted out and I can mount the drive directly to the VM, does anyone have an experience with whether the drive should be mounted to the VM as scsi, ide, or virtio? (I know virtio was recommend in the linked ServerFault page, but I hadn't heard of it before now since I mainly use VMWare).

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Run `sudo virt-manager`, no need to connect as root. Don't know if `virtio` works for physical devices...

Comment: @izx, thanks for your reply! should that make a make a difference even though virt-manager is being run on my desktop and not the server?

Answer (score 17):

Having the exact same need, I found the [following](http://ronaldevers.nl/2012/10/14/adding-a-physical-disk-kvm-libvirt.html).

(the whole following text comes from the above source)

> It can’t be done with virt-manager. That one took me a while to figure out. As far as I can tell, virt-manager works with storage pools. You can make a disk into a storage pool, but you can’t add an existing disk directly to a VM.
>
> Luckily the fix is easy: you add the disk to the domain’s xml config file by hand. So open up /etc/libvirt/qemu/.xml in your favourite editor and add a  section to the  section:

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
  <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
  <source dev='/dev/md/storage'/>
  <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
</disk>
```

> This will make the host’s /dev/md/storage available in the guest as /dev/vdb. After changing a domain’s config by hand, you have to reload the config by hand. Log in to your host and issue this command:

```
# virsh define /etc/libvirt/qemu/jetsetetser.xml
Domain jetser defined from /etc/libvirt/qemu/jetsetetser.xml
```

> Here is a nice resource with more information about managing vms with libvirt : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Managing

I strongly recommend you follow the advice given by smccloud. This works like a charm for me. Beware to **not** mount any volume in the physical drives used in your guest, or you will severely damage its filesystem !

Comment: Instead of `virsh define...`, the recommendation is to use `virsh edit <NAME>` This allows you to edit the XML in your favorite text editor and have the changes automatically update the VM.

Comment: I get permission denied when trying to access the `/dev/sd...` block device even though I've unmounted it from the host :(

Answer (score 15):

Although this has been answered, rather than using /dev/sda you should use /dev/disk/by-id/ where you get  from

```
    ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
```

That way you are covered just in case the disk changes from /dev/sda to /dev/sdb.

Comment: Currently this is the only answer (that has ever been) posted on this question. There's some information in comments that might help, but as far as I can tell it's far from certain that they will fix the problem. You might consider expanding this to provide a full solution. If parts of your solution have been devised by others you can always cite them and link to them. I doubt [izx](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144894/add-physical-disk-to-kvm-virtual-machine/159323#comment174227_144894) would mind ..especially as (when I comment now) izx hasn't signed on to the site for over a year.

Comment: I'm using `virsh attach-device domain XML-file...` to attach disks. Can you also use disk-id in the `<source dev='/dev/...'/>`element?

Answer (score 1):

First enable xml editing in Preferences in virt-manager.

Then add a normal file-backed SATA disk in virt-manager GUI for your VM. You can set the disk size to 1GB or you can choose any not used disk images.

Then in virt-manager GUI, in the xml pane of that disk you just created, the existing xml should be like:

```
<disk type="file" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
  <source file="/var/lib/libvirt/images/vol-1.qcow2"/>
  <target dev="sdc" bus="sata"/>
  <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="2"/>
</disk>
```

change it to:

```
<disk type="block" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
  <source dev="/dev/sda"/>
  <target dev="vda" bus="sata"/>
  <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="2"/>
</disk>
```

Then press Apply button.

Note that you should keep the "address" tag untouched and change other parameter as above.

Here "/dev/sda" is the physical drive on host to be used by VM.

The name "vda" is just like "sda, sdb...", you can use "vdb,vdc..." etc, too.

This works for Ubuntu 22.04 host and Windows 10 VM. Windows doesn't have virtIO driver so choosing SATA is easier (not sure whether performance have difference between SATA and virtIO)